# How to convert a string containing several float numbers into an array of float in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a text file which contains float characters line by line as

```
    15.723
    17.567
```

I tried reading the file and after doing this

```
with open('<path_to_file>/writefile.txt', 'r') as fin:
    data_read = fin.read()
```

When I print *data_read*, I get

```
'15.723\n17.567\n'
```

Now I need to save this string into an array containg

```
float_array[0]=15.723
float_array[1]=17.567
```

How do I do the conversion?

I tried

```
print(float(data_read))
res = data_read.astype(float)
print(res)
```

And I got

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15.723\n17.567\n'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I am expecting something like
float_array[0]=15.723
float_array[1]=17.567

Comment: When you say array, do you mean list?

Comment: @PM77-1 Ok... What and how should I split? The '\n' delimiter serves as saperating each variable. How do I differentiate each variable after splitting?

Comment: @MadPhysicist array list doesn't matter. As long as I can access the variable as float

Comment: @usrp_hacker. It does matter, because those two words mean different things in python. If you're not sure, you want a list.

Comment: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split your string into individual numbers:

```
list_of_strings = data_read.split()
```

Now you can apply `float` to each element:

```
list_of_floats = [float(x) for x in list_of_strings if x]
```

The check `if x` discards the last empty element if your file ends with a newline. If it doesn't, you can do

```
list_of_floats = list(map(float, list_of_strings))
```

Or you can strip the data first:

```
list_of_strings = data_read.strip().split()
```

Comment: Better be explicit here and pass the splitting parameter `data_read.split('\n')`

Comment: @alec_djinn. Not passing it in will automatically strip off unnecessary whitespace too, which is nice.

Comment: I tried but I am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    list_of_floats = list(map(float, list_of_strings))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: @usrp_hacker. Good call. Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file directly into a list of strings (using `readlines()`) and then convert every line to float. So you don't have to use `split()`

```
with open('<path_to_file>/writefile.txt', 'r') as fin:
    data_read = fin.readlines()
numbers = list(map(float, data_read))
```

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '20,807\n' I am getting such error. I am living in Europe, so the , is used as floating point here

Comment: why then you have ``.`` in you sample data and not ``,``? But anyway it is another problem, unrelated to your inital question.

Comment: I did data_read = data_read.replace(',', '.'). In Europe, the , is used as floating point. I wasn't sure if that is causing any issue so I did this.

Comment: It works. My bad. There was a EOL at the end of the file which was preventing the numbers from getting converted to float. It's all good now